# What is $f^{-1}(1)$ where $f(x,y,z)=(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2)^2+z^2$

Tags: functions, inverse

> I was doing a problem that requires finding the inverse image of $1$ by the function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ where
> $$f(x,y,z)=(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2)^2+z^2$$

$(x,y,z)\in f^{-1}(1) \iff (\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2)^2+z^2=1$

$(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2)^2+z^2=1$

$\implies (\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2)^2=1-z^2$

I am not sure how to complete. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's a torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Check the implicit equation part in https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Torus.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang I knew that my answer was algebraically okay, but my visualization attempt kept hanging on it **not** representing the surface of a sphere.  +1 to your comment, which I now am able to visualize as consistent with my answer.

Comment: Re my previous comment, if you take the torus, and make a cross sectional cut that goes through the center of the torus and is perpendicular to the $(xy)$ plane  (i.e. if the torus is resting on a table, you make the cut orthogonal to the table), then at each of the two intersections of the surface of the torus with the cut, you have a perfect circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $g:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by:

The domain of $g$ is $\{z : 1 \leq |z| \leq 3\}.$

$g(z) = |z| - 2.$

Then, similar to the idea that $\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1$, you imagine the points on the unit circle in $\mathbb{R^2}$, where the $x$ coordinate is $g(x + iy)$, and the $y$ coordinate is the value $z$ from the original function $f$.

Then, these points on the unit circle will represent all possible ordered triplets $(x,y,z)$ from the original $\mathbb{R^3}$ such that $f(x,y,z) = 1.$

Comment: This seems to be the *right* answer. Plus one.

Comment: For some reason there is no function shown after "given by:"

Comment: @TheVal For the function $g$, its domain and specification are on the two lines following the "given by:" line.  I intentionally used this **non-standard** approach to force focusing on the function's domain **before** focusing on the function's specification.  I am not experienced in this area, and recognize that experienced mathSE reviewers may regard these beginning lines as **needing editing**.  If so, I respect that, and invite editing suggestions; alternatively, you are welcome to edit the response yourself, and I will probably approve it.

Comment: @user2661923 Golly! Thanks for the clarification, my bad

Answer (score 2):

Since $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$, then $f^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3$, then the solution of $f^{-1}(1)$ is the 3-tuple $(x,y,z)$ such that:
$$
(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2)^2=1-z^2
$$
That seems pretty much the answer. If you wish you can expand the above expression and recover some form of conic section, if there exists (I doubt it does, due to the sqrt term).

Answer (score 2):

The upshot is that you have an fourth-degree surface in $3$-space. Probably too hard for a purely algebraic analysis. But I think that the approach of @user2661923 is the right one. The whole thing looks as if it might be a torus sitting in space.

Here, however is how that purely algebraic approach would work, going one more step than @TheVal has: we start with his displayed formula,
\begin{align}
\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2\right)^2&=1-z^2\\
x^2+y^2-4\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+4&=1-z^2\\
x^2+y^2+z^2+3&=4\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\
x^4+y^4+z^4+\cdots+9&=16x^2+16y^2\,,
\end{align}
where I did expand the left-hand side of the last two lines, but the result is probably not helpful to the understanding. The steps are, first, to expand the parenthesis of the first line; second, to isolate the radical on the right; third, to square both sides. We’re doing algebraic geometry at this stage, folks, so you don’t worry about extraneous solutions. Gather all terms to the left and get a quartic polynomial in three variables. I would not presume to proclaim authoritatively that this is irreducible, but I would at least bet a nickel on the claim.

Comment: Thank you for expanding my answer Professor!